# Rationale for EXCLUDE mode in mutlicast IGMPv3 / MLDv2

Tags: protocol-theory, multicast, igmp

Both IGMPv3 and MLDv2 have an *include* and an *exclude* mode, where a multicast listener can specify to either listen only for packets from some list of source addresses (include) or only for packets that don't come from some list of source addresses (exclude).

What's the rationale for the exclude mode? Any examples for use cases where this mode makes sense?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin: No, the answer didn't help me, and no, I still don't know the rationale, so I can't provide my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The generic answer to your question would be "exclude mode is to be used when the list of IPs you want to listen to is longer then the list of IPs you do not want to listen to".

The most common use case is actually the most extreme case: listening for packets from **any source**. This means using exclude mode with an **empty exclude list**. Since IGMPv1 and v2 do not support source-specific multicast, this is the way their behaviour for a "group join" is emulated in IGMPv3.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the empty list. The question is about a use case where you'd actually know a list of IPs you **don't** want to listen to, and the rationale for this. Why should applications not want to some specific IPs of a multicast group? Are there examples where this is actually used by applications?

Answer (score 0):

@dirkt Did you find out the rationale ? Because I find myself asking the same question. But here's what I think:

- so, according to rfc3376, it is possible for a client to block the traffic from a single specific source while accepting from all the others: just have the client send a Membership Report with Record Type MODE_IS_EXCLUDE and the source address you want to block. But the question is: how would a router process this? A router has to create (*,G) or (S,G) forwarding states based on the Reports received from clients. What forwarding state would a router create for such a Report?
- I believe that rfc4604 tries to answer this in section 2.2.2.: it should be impossible. Record types MODE_IS_EXCLUDE and CHANGE_TO_EXCLUDE_MODE must not be used by SSM aware clients. I believe this means that these record types must be used for any-source multicast only. For example, to join an asm group by using CHANGE_TO_EXCLUDE_MODE and an empty source list, and MODE_IS_EXCLUDE with an empty source list to signal that the client still is subscribed to the asm group.

Whoever might know better, please confirm or infirm this response.